# rxjs Filter observable stream not working correctly unexpected results

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my component I have two form fields. First one is to select a `priceMin` and second is to select a `priceMax`.

Then I have an observable I want to filter.

```
export class ListingsComponent implements OnInit {
  listings$: Observable<Listing[]>;
  filterForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private firestore: FirestoreService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  get priceMin() {
    return this.filterForm.get('priceMin');
  }
  get priceMax() {
    return this.filterForm.get('priceMax');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
      priceMin: [null],
      priceMax: [null]
    });

    this.listings$ = this.firestore.getListings().pipe(
      switchMap(listings => {
        return merge(

          this.priceMin.valueChanges.pipe(
            map(priceMin => {
              return listings.filter(listing => {
                return listing.profile.price.hour >= priceMin;
              });
            })
          ),

          this.priceMax.valueChanges.pipe(
            map(priceMax => {
              return listings.filter(listing => {
                return listing.profile.price.hour <= priceMax;
              });
            })
          )

        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

It works (I mean no errors) but the filtered observable behaves weird and the result is not as I'm expecting it to be.

On the preview image:

Ad 1. The results are correct when I select for the first time.

Ad 2. Then, when I change `minPrice` it looks like it ignores the `maxPrice`.

Ad 3. (Not in the preview img) Then, when I change `maxPrice` it ignores `minPrice` and so on...

[image: Preview]

What can possibly cause this behavior and how to fix this?

`Working code:`

```
this.listings$ = combineLatest(this.priceMin.valueChanges, this.priceMax.valueChanges).pipe(
      switchMap(price => {
        return this.firestore.getListings().pipe(
          map(listings => {
            return listings.filter(listing => {
              return (
                listing.profile.price.hour >= price[0] && listing.profile.price.hour <= price[1]
              );
            });
          })
        );
      })
    );
```

Finally, I used `Behavior Subject` to hold an initial value of the filters.

```
this.priceMin.valueChanges.pipe(map(value => this.filterPriceMin.next(value))).subscribe();

const filters$ = combineLatest(
      this.filterPriceMin, // filter 0
      this.filterPriceMax // filter 1
    );
```

Comment: The only problem with the working code is it won't display any items until both observables in combineLatest emits a value. But this is not a part of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem does not lie in your `filter` because that's just simple `Array.filter()` and I don't see anything wrong with it.

Probably the problem is `merge` operator. `merge` will emit if either of the child `Observables` emits. E.x: `priceMin` emits then `merge` emits then `priceMax` emits then `merge` emits `priceMax` value.

To get both values when the observable emits, you might wanna change `merge` to `combineLatest`. Make sure to change your logic a little bit because `combineLatest` returns `[valueFromObs1, valueFromObs2]` as an `Array`, unlike `merge`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try with `combineLatest` then and let you know.

Comment: Yeah, probably another `map` after the `combineLatest` would do it ;)

Comment: OK. Seem to be working now. I updated my question with an answer. Thanks :)